# jQuery Passing text input value to plugin option

Tags: jquery, forms, barcode

I can't find quite the answer I'm looking for anywhere.  I have a plugin that generates barcodes. All you do is tell it what element to render the barcode, and it spits it out. For example:

```
$("#barcode-target").barcode("Output Goes Here", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});
```

will put a barcode that says "Output Goes Here" into the div #barcode-target. 
However, I need it to generate a barcode with the value of a certain text input. I tried doing something along the lines of

```
$(function(){
    $("#barcode").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#barcode-target").text(value);
    }).keyup();
});
```

Which, of course, only puts plain characters in the div. I'm stuck!

**Edit**
I've also tried

```
$(function(){
    var barcodeVal = $("#barcode").val();
    $("#barcode-target").barcode("barcodeVal", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});
});
```

Still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a barcode the way you said:

```
$(function(){
  $("#barcode").keyup(function () {
    $("#barcode-target").barcode($(this).val(), "code39", {
      barWidth:2, 
      barHeight:30
    });
  }).keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your edit, if you're wanting to pass the value of the `barcodeVal` variable, you shouldn't put the name in quotes.

```
$(function(){
    var barcodeVal = $("#barcode").val();
     // no quotation marks----------v
    $("#barcode-target").barcode( barcodeVal, "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});
});
```

Otherwise you were sending a String literal.

Or you could forego the variable, and place the `.val()` call directly in the call to `barcode()`.

```
$(function(){
     // Get the .val() while calling barcode
    $("#barcode-target").barcode( $("#barcode").val(), "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});
});
```